# Shortcut for screen percentage

Tags: flutter, media-queries, screen

Is there a shortcut to access the screen size without tapping all this ?

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65
```

I thought I could put it inside a *function* in an *helper* and pass the percent as a *param*, but the context in naturaly unaccessible

Answer (score 1):

You could use a package named [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) from pub dev. It is very simple to use and easy to understand. what it simply does is that it divides the screen into percentages. See the below example:

```
Container(
  width: 20.w,    //It will take a 20% of screen width
  height:30.h     //It will take a 30% of screen height
)
```

So in it the `.w` is for the width of the screen, `.h` is for the height, and `.sp` is for the fonts.